# How do I burn an ISO 9660 formatted CD on Windows?

Tags: windows, burning, cd-burning

ISO 9660 is and older format required by older DVD/CD players. Windows doesn't clearly state how to burn this format.

Comment: There are many third-party tools to walk you through burning a CD or DVD in a number of formats, including ISO 9660. See http://www.thewindowsplanet.com/3025/6-best-free-blu-raycddvd-burning-software-for-windows.htm

Comment: How is this an "unclear" question? This even states the ISO format, how clear do you want it?

Answer (score 1):

Windows writes UDF format by default, but you can download an external program to write ISO 9660 format. This program does it if you select Data Disc, then `Disc -> Format` https://cdburnerxp.se